# How can I remove an uploaded file from GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I wanted to create a `New pull request` to an R package GitHub repository and I uploaded my file to a wrong directory of the package by chance.  I am just a contributor and not the owner of this repository. How can I delete this uploaded file? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Open issue in the repository and ask for removal or open pull request that does it and explain why.